# OPCUA: detect and cast custom method input-parameters

Tags: python, opc-ua

## Problem

When we take a look at https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/asyncua/common/methods.py#L14, we see that the pattern to call an opcua method would be in the form of `node.call_method('method_name', *args)`.

Now the protocol expect the `args` to be cast to the right datatypes. If you take a look at https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/discussions/1278, you see that the custom datatype is pulled from `ua` and a value is built this way: `ua._DB_Com_In_(ID=99, Value1=100, Value2=199)`.

But as interactive / dynamic client, I'm unable to know in advance what datatype I need... I would need something like:

```py
args = cast_for_method('method_name', [{'ID': 99, 'Value1': 100, 'Value2': 199}, 10])
result = node.call_method('method_name'), *args)
```

## What I tried

Get the type from the variable called `0:InputArguments` of the `method_name` which is the place where the parameters will be stored.

I tried to call `read_data_type()`, `read_data_type_as_variant_type()` (this actually should return the right type but does not work for a method, I get all existing defined types instead).

`read_data_value()`, `read_type_definition()` and `read_value()` looks promising but I'm not there yet. I know that `read_data_type_as_variant_type()` is normally returning the datatype, therefore, I try to find an object with the above function that enable me to call this function so that I can finally get the type I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the value of the "0:InputArguments" with read_value.
This returns a list of [Arguments](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part3/v104/docs/8.6).

Each dataType in the Arguments can be translated to class like this:

```
from asyncua.ua import ObjectIds
from asyncua import ua
base_type_list = {
ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.Null): None,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.Boolean): bool,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.SByte): ua.SByte,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.Byte): ua.Byte,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.Int16): ua.Int16,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.UInt16): ua.UInt16,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.Int32): ua.Int32,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.UInt32): ua.UInt32,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.Int64): ua.Int64,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.UInt64): ua.UInt64,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.Float): ua.Float,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.Double): ua.Double,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.String): ua.String,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.DateTime): ua.DateTime,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.Guid): ua.Guid,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.ByteString): ua.ByteString,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.XmlElement): ua.XmlElement,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.NodeId): ua.NodeId,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.ExpandedNodeId): ua.ExpandedNodeId,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.StatusCode): ua.StatusCode,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.QualifiedName): ua.QualifiedName,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.LocalizedText): ua.LocalizedText,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.Structure): ua.ExtensionObject,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.DataValue): ua.DataValue,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.BaseVariableType): ua.Variant,
    ua.NodeId(ObjectIds.DiagnosticInfo): ua.DiagnosticInfo,
} 

def get_class_from_nodeid(datatype_nodeid):
  
   # check all type dicts   
   sources = [base_type_list, ua.basetype_by_datatype, ua.extension_objects_by_datatype, ua.enums_by_datatype]
   cls = None
   for src in sources:
       cls = src.get(datatype_nodeid, None)
       if cls is not None:
          return cls       
   return cls
```

Comment: Hi @Schroeder, I found a solution that goes very well in the same direction. The end is a bit different, from the nodeid, with `get_node()`, I get the `browse_name` and extract the type name to search it in `ua`. I still want to try your approach, even if I do not fully understand it, because it contains less lines of code ^^.

Comment: The browsename is also an idea. My way saves some network calls. The sources are dicts that are used to convert python datatypes to binary.

Comment: Just one additional question, why do you need `base_type_list`  when I would expect `ua.basetype_by_datatype` to deliver the same?  Also `ObjectIds.ExtensionObject` and `ObjectIds.Variant` do not exist.

Comment: And I have an additional side effects regarding the `NodeIdType` because `NodeIdType.TwoByte` and `NodeIdType.Numeric` are not resolved by `get_class_from_nodeid `.

Comment: I updated the code this should work with any nodeid

Comment: I just have a final question. `ObjectIds.ExtensionObject` and `ObjectIds.Variant` do not exist on my side (asyncua 1.0.3). On which version are you?